# white space Regex in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

according to [mysql regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)  we can use `[[:space:]]*` instead of `\s*` 
so I have this query

```
select * from onet.tools_and_technology where t2_example  Rlike '[[:space:]]*C++[[:space:]]*';
```

but it gives me this error

> Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from
>   regexp

what I'm missing here??!!

Comment: it should be `c\+\+` if you want to match `c++` literally

Comment: sorry to tell you that but it gives the same error

Comment: c++ here is a programming language if you don't know what I mean in the query

Comment: escape the `+` twice as `c\\+\\+`

Comment: I'd imagine they're aware.  But `+` in Regex means "one or more of the previous token".  So `C+` would match `C`, `CC`, `CCC`, etc.  But `C++` doesn't mean anything.  `\+` matches the _literal_ symbol "+".

Comment: ok very nice its worked perfectly thank you very much @rock321987 and user2478398

Comment: `[[:space:]]*` matches whether or not that is a space there.  That is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` character is similar to the `*` character in a regex: they're meta characters.

You need to escape each character with `\`. Because you are working in a string, you will need to escape the escape: `'[[:space:]]*C\\+\\+[[:space:]]*'`

---

Your problem can be solved without regexes, though:  `LIKE '% c++ %'`

This is much more readable.

Comment: yeh I know but some skills don't need space and some of them need it so I used regex to satisfy both cases

Comment: @Abeerzaroor Well, there's actually no reason to even include the space in that case...